# Can anyone help me with this error?? 0x80041002

Tags: c#

unknown error 0x80041002

c# programming

I have a listview

I am able to via openfiledialog, open file paths and put them into the listview

I will save them in text file format and close my c# winform application

Open it up again and tried to place the saved files back into the listview.

I will "check" the checkered box on the files that i want to run

When i clicked on the "run" button,

Unknown Error: 0x80041002 
Pops out

```
foreach (ListViewItem subItem in list.CheckedItems) 
{ 
    string checkedItems = list.CheckedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text; 
    Process proc = Process.Start(checkedItems); 
    proc.WaitForExit(); // Waits for the process to end. 
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do on click of run button? can you share the code?

Comment: How about some code samples, where the error occurs?

Comment: foreach (ListViewItem subItem in list.CheckedItems)
{


  string checkedItems = list.CheckedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
 

 Process proc = Process.Start(checkedItems); // run checked batch files sequencially from command line.
  

proc.WaitForExit(); // Waits for the process to end. 

}

Comment: Edit your question with the code rather than posting it a comment - it will format better (as long you select the "code" icon).

Answer (score 2):

That error is thrown when you pass a wrong path to Process.Start

You should add to your code some verification

```
foreach (ListViewItem subItem in list.CheckedItems) 
{ 
    if(list.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        string checkedItems = list.CheckedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text; 
        if(File.Exists(checkedItems)
        {
            Process proc = Process.Start(checkedItems); 
            proc.WaitForExit(); // Waits for the process to end. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Wildhorn, I am quite new to C# language and i learned that i can use this foreach method for "checked" listview items and i'm working on a simple interface whereby the functions mentioned above can be done.

sorry to say that I do not understand what you are trying to say
If possible can you show me what you mean by examples??

Comment: My bad, the error is not coming from that, it comes from you Process.Start (I edited my post to reflect this)